# Debugging TypeScript with commonjs modules in the browser

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, gulp, browserify

**What I need**

1. In my TypeScript code I need to be able to import 3rd party libraries that uses CommonJS module system.
2. Compile typescript into javascript
3. Load the javascript in the browser and debug the original typescript source files.

**What I've done**

1. In tsconfig.json I set

   ```
   "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node"
   }
   ```

2. I've created gulp task that compiles typescript files into `build/scripts/commonjs` folder including source maps, and then another task that uses browserify to bundle the files from `build/scripts/commonjs` also with source maps:

   ```
   var gulp = require('gulp'),
       browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
       sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
       typescript = require('gulp-typescript');

   gulp.task('compile-typescript', function(){

       var tsProject = typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json');
       var tsResult = tsProject.src() // instead of gulp.src(...)
               .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
               .pipe(typescript(tsProject));

       return tsResult.js
           .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
           .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts/commonjs'));

   });

   gulp.task("browserify", function () {
       return gulp.src('build/scripts/commonjs/app.js')
           .pipe(browserify({
               debug : true, //this generates source map
       }))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts/'));
   });
   ```

The output from `compile-typescript' is:

```
build
   scripts
      commonjs
         -app.js
         -app.js.map
         -testmodule.map
         -testmodule.js.map
```

and from browserify:

```
build
   scripts
      -app.js //this contains source map inside
```

I include the bundle ('build/scripts/app.js') in html and it works in the browser, however debugging debugging works only in the compiled javascript files.

Is is possible to first compile the typescript and then bundle it while still be able to debug the original source